# Where did Vasco Núñez de Balboa first see the South Ocean?

Tags: spanish-empire, age-of-discovery, americas, central-america

Do we know the exact place in Panama where [Vasco Núñez de Balboa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasco_N%C3%BA%C3%B1ez_de_Balboa) first saw the South Ocean?

(If so, do we have a picture of this place where he saw the two oceans at the same time?)

In *Decisive Moments in History* from Stefan Zweig, it is written that Balboa and his men built at this location a Christian cross with the initials of the King of Spain. Is the cross still there or is there some monument that marks this point?

Comment: The cross was most likely wooden, and so would have rotted away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The place is not known with certainty, but some googling revealed two possible candidates:

One of them is [Pechito Parado](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Cerro+Pechito+Parado/@8.5538435,-78.3435298,12z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x8e53bf83fdf34525:0xb9a19af308c4b611!8m2!3d8.6172222!4d-78.2988889), a mountain near a very small village named Quebrada Eusebio. This place was visited by a group of young people in the [Ruta Quetzal BBVA](http://www.rutabbva.com/TLRQ/index.php?id=63&no_cache=1&no_cache=1&expid=29&jornadaid=779&cHash=ecaf8b370d), a cultural exchange program, on the anniversary of the discovery in 2013 (more info, in Spanish, in [this Spanish newspaper](http://www.elmundo.es/elmundo/2013/07/06/ciencia/1373144306.html)).

The other candidate is a mountain named **Urrucallala** and is mentioned in some academical journals such as Ángel Rubio's [*La ruta de Balboa y el descubrimiento del Océano Pacífico*](https://books.google.com/books?redir_esc=y&hl=es&id=YB9jAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=Urrucallala) (1965) and an article in the [*Hispanic American Historical Review*](https://books.google.com/books?hl=es&id=DY01AAAAIAAJ&dq=urrucallala&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=urrucallala) (1967), both in snippet view so I can't read them in full. Rubio, however, mentions both mountains and says they were very close to each other.

Comment: This answer is good enough that it convinced me to upvote the question too.

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikipedia articles both in [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasco_N%C3%BA%C3%B1ez_de_Balboa) and [Spanish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasco_N%C3%BA%C3%B1ez_de_Balboa) that spot was the top of a mountain.

Britannica mentions [“a peak in Darién”](https://global.britannica.com/biography/Vasco-Nunez-de-Balboa) around quotes.

“A peak in Darién” is also the end of [a poem of John Keats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_First_Looking_into_Chapman%27s_Homer), in which he (wrongly) attributes the discovery to Hernán Cortés.

So it seems the name of the mountain or peak is not recorded.